# List.count=0 when get data from XML file to List()

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm having an `user.xml` file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myXML>
  <RealName>Nguyen Van A</RealName>
  <Email>vyclarks@gmail.com</Email>
  <Phone>2165421</Phone>
  <Address>Ho Chi Minh</Address>
  <Link1>dtvt</Link1>
  <Link2></Link2>
  <Link3></Link3>
</myXML>
```

and I have code to get data from xml file:

```
public class user
    {
        public string realname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string link1 { get; set; }
        public string link2 { get; set; }
        public string link3 { get; set; }
    }

public void getUser()
    {
            List<user> us = (
                      from e in
                      XDocument.Load("user.xml").Root.Elements("myXML")
                      select new user
                      {
                        realname = (string)e.Element("RealName"),
                        email = (string)e.Element("Email"),
                        phone = (string)e.Element("Phone"),
                        address = (string)e.Element("Address"),
                        link1 = (string)e.Element("Link1"),
                        link2 = (string)e.Element("Link2"),
                        link3 = (string)e.Element("Link3")
                      }
                      ).ToList();
//get data from list to label

            lblrealname.Text = us[0].ToString();
            lblmail.Text = us[1].ToString();
            lblphone.Text = us[2].ToString();
            lbladd.Text = us[3].ToString();
            lbllink1.Text = us[4].ToString();
            lbllink2.Text = us[5].ToString();
            lbllink3.Text = us[6].ToString();

    }
```

But when I built, it has an error in line:`lblrealname.Text = profiles[0].ToString();` this is the content: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Then I debug, the `us.count = 0` ---> I wonder if that my code above has some mistakes so there no item in list `us`.

Help!! I cannot find where is wrong and is there any better way to get data from that xml file.

Comment: What is `profiles` collection? Where do you get that from?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky sorry, I copy code from my project and has some editing, us is the same with profile, I will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split UI and Data Access logic. Make your method return `User` object instead of being void. Thus there is only one root in your xml, you don't need to write query which returns list of users - simply access root node directly. Also use [PascalCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for type names, methods and properties:

```
public User GetUser()
{
    var root = XDocument.Load("user.xml").Root;
    return new User {
         RealName = (string)root.Element("RealName"),
         Email = (string)root.Element("Email"),
         Phone = (string)root.Element("Phone"),
         Address = (string)root.Element("Address"),
         Link1 = (string)root.Element("Link1"),
         Link2 = (string)root.Element("Link2"),
         Link3 = (string)root.Element("Link3")
    };
}
```

Displaying user on UI:

```
public void DisplayUser(User user)
{
    lblrealname.Text = user.RealName;
    lblmail.Text = user.Email;
    lblphone.Text = user.Phone;
    lbladd.Text = user.Address;
    lbllink1.Text = user.Link1;
    lbllink2.Text = user.Link2;
    lbllink3.Text = user.Link3;
}
```

And all together:

```
var user = GetUser();
DispalylUser(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line

```
from e in XDocument.Load("user.xml").Root.Elements("myXML")
```

results in 0 results because `<myXML>` **is** the root, and it doesn't look like it contains any nested `<myXML>` within it.

---

The following should work.

```
from e in XDocument.Load("user.xml").Elements("myXML")
```

and if you don't need an enumerable, you can just take the root

```
var element = XDocument.Load("user.xml").Root;
```

Comment: One more point - it's not very good idea at all to write `from e in root` query, because there always will be one item (if xml is not empty) and there is not need to work with enumerable data

Comment: @lazyberezovsky is there any better way for my problem, because it has some empty field in my xml file

Comment: @Sam I am: as you recommended, the count=1 right now, but it still has an error in the line:lblmail.Text = profiles[1].ToString();  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. ??? Help

Comment: @VyClarks apparently, the `profiles` collection only has 1 element.  It's hard to see why this is without seeing where `profiles` is instanciated

Comment: I really dont know why, I can get the RealName so why I cannot get the other fields with the same syntax??? Help!!!